# Select with different conditions on multiple different fields of a single table

Tags: sql-server

hello i want something like the fallowing (without using sub queries):

```
select planName where period=1 as 1stPlan
select planName where period=2 as 2ndPlan
select planName where period=3 as 3ndPlan
...
FROM plan inner join project ON Project.Id=Plan.ProjectId
```

thank you

Comment: Look into using PIVOT: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select
  plan1.planName,
  plan2.planName,
  plan3.planName 
FROM project 
  left join plan plan1 ON Project.Id=Plan1.ProjectId and Plan1.period=1 
  left join plan plan2 ON Project.Id=Plan2.ProjectId and Plan2.period=2 
  left join plan plan3 ON Project.Id=Plan3.ProjectId and Plan3.period=3
```

Comment: which one is better in performance in this case? left joins or sub queries ?

Comment: @Mohsen: Can't say. You need to look at the execution plan.